# aufteilen vs. austeilen vs. verteilen

Tags: difference, meaning-in-context

Wo liegt der Unterschied zwischen diesen drei Verben?

> der Spielleiter **verteilt** die Rollen (Duden)
>
> der Spielleiter **teilt** die Rollen **aus**

Bedeutet der erste Satz, dass es eine bestimmte Anzahl an Rollen gibt und beispielsweise nicht jeder Schüler eine Rolle bekommt?
Und was den zweiten Satz anbelangt so verstehe ich ihn so, dass jeder Schüler eine Rolle bekommt.

Ist das richtig?

Und was ist der Unterschied zwischen aufteilen und austeilen?

> z.B. Post, Suppe **austeilen** (Duden)
>
> z.B. Schokolade unter den Kindern austeilen/den Gewinn, die Beute,
>    **aufteilen** (Duden)

Duden sagt das folgende: "austeilen" - an einen bestimmten Personenkreis verteilen; "verteilen" - an mehrere Personen austeilen. Für "austeilen" gibt es das Beispiel - Hefte an die Schüler austeilen.

Aber auf einer Internetseite habe ich gelesen, dass man in diesem Kontext auch "verteilen" benutzen kann. Im thefreedictionary steht, dass "austeilen" einsammeln und verteilen bedeutet, und "verteilen" für Dinge gleicher oder ähnlicher Art verwendet wird. Deshalb bin ich in Verwirrung geraten. Ich kann nicht begreifen, wann sie als Synonyme gelten und wann nicht.

Answer (score 3):

Ich nehme als Beispiel statt der Rollen mal einen physischen Stapel Spielkarten. Wenn ich jedem Mitspieler reihum Karten gebe und dann sage, dass ich die Karten

- **verteile**, betone ich, dass der Kartenstapel (das **Ganze**) **aufgelöst** wird.
- **austeile**, betone ich die **Transaktion** der Karten zu den Mitspielern.
- **aufteile**, betone ich, dass die Karten (**Teile**) am Ende **klar getrennt** sind.

In diesem Fall sind die drei Verben also mehr oder weniger synonym, mit einer anders gewichteten Betonung.

Allerdings kann ich nicht jedes Verb auf jedes Szenario anwenden. **Verteilen** ist das allgemeine Wort und kann anstelle von **aufteilen** und **austeilen** benutzt werden. Umgekehrt gibt es allerdings Fälle, in denen nur **verteilen** passt. **Aufteilen** und **austeilen** sind generell untereinander nicht austauschbar.

- Wenn ich zum Beispiel die Karten quer über den Tisch werfe, dann kann ich nur sagen, dass ich sie **verteile** (der Stapel löst sich auf). Ich habe sie nicht **ausgeteilt** (ich adressiere sie an keinen speziellen Empfänger) oder **aufgeteilt** (ich beabsichtige keine klare Abtrennung von Untermengen).
- Wenn ich von einer **ausgeteilten** Karte (eine intakte, die ich jemandem gegeben habe) spreche, ist das etwas ganz anderes als von einer **aufgeteilten** Karte (eine, die ich zerschnitten habe, ohne Angabe, wo die Teile jetzt sind). In beiden Fällen kann ich jedoch sagen, dass die Karte **verteilt** ist.

---

Was dein Beispiel angeht:

"*der Spielleiter verteilt die Rollen*" und "*der Spielleiter teilt die Rollen aus*" sind ohne Bedeutungsverlust austauschbar (nur die Betonung verschiebt sich natürlich... zweiteres klingt mehr nach sequenziellem Zuweisen).

Comment: Nö, *verteilen* bezeichnet keine perfekte, totale Verwendung, jedenfalls heute nicht mehr. Wenn ich bspw. Noten verteile, sind diese unbegrenzt. Soweit der einzige Zweifel.

Comment: @vectory Gutes Beispiel. Vielleicht sollte man zu *verteilen* einfach sagen: "Wird benutzt, wenn die andern beiden nicht passen".

Answer (score 2):

Beim DWDS benutzt die Erklärung [jeweils](https://www.dwds.de/wb/verteilen) das [andere](https://www.dwds.de/wb/austeilen) [Wort](https://www.dwds.de/wb/aufteilen)...

Beim ersten Satz ("verteilt die Rollen") sehe ich keine zwingende Implikation, dass es mehr Schüler als Rollen gibt. Lediglich, dass es mehr als eine Rolle zu verteilen gibt und alle Rollen vergeben werden (müssen).

Den zweiten Satz ("teilt Rollen aus") würde ich vermutlich dann verwenden, falls (planmäßig) kein Schüler leer ausgeht - auch wenn es meiner folgenden Erklärung ein wenig widerspricht  <sup>;-)</sup>.

Grundsätzlich sind die Verben synonym. Das zeigt sich auch in den folgenden Erläuterungen, z.B. "Verteilungsschlüssel" bei "aufteilen".

[Update] Die Hinweise aus den Kommentaren machen (mir) deutlich, dass es eine ziemliche Grauzone gibt und meine unten notierte Differenzierung nur begrenzt gültig ist. [/Update]

**Verteilen**

- Ziel ist es, von dem was verteilt wird, alles zu verteilen
- D.h., verteile ich einen Kuchen, dann will ich am Ende alles verteilt haben, es kann mehr potentielle als tatsächliche Empfänger geben.

**Austeilen**

- Ziel ist es, etwas Vorhandenes weniger werden zu lassen, indem es andere bekommen
- d.h., teile ich einen Kuchen aus, dann ist am Ende weniger als vorher da, es ist unerheblich, wieviel am Ende noch da ist

**Aufteilen**

- Ähnlich verteilen geht es darum, alles zu verteilen.
- Den Unterschied sehe ich darin, dass die Empfänger eine gewisse Anspruchshaltung haben, nach einem Verteilungsschlüssel x entsprechend Anteile zu bekommen.
- Im Gegensatz zum Verteilen ist es darauf angelegt, dass der Aufteilende einen eigenen Anteil bekommt.
- D.h., teile ich Kuchen auf, könnte jeder seinem Alter ein entsprechend großes Stück haben wollen.

Dazu ein paar "Nebenbedeutungen" & Beispiele

- austeilen:

  - Schläge austeilen = ich schlage andere
  - Suppe austeilen = ich stehe am Topf und gebe jedem eine Kelle voll - ich höre auf, sobald keine Suppe mehr da oder keiner mehr ansteht oder ich keine Lust mehr habe
- verteilen:

  - der Stromverteiler gibt Strom per se zu gleichen Teilen an alle Empfänger
  - der Inhalt der umgefallenen Obstkiste verteilt sich auf der Straße = die Kiste ist danach leer
- aufteilen

  - Länder aufteilen = Kriegsgewinner teilen unter sich auf, wer wieviel Land bekommt

Comment: "Der Bauer verteilte Äpfel unter die Besucher" könnte man also nicht sagen, wenn man am Ende nicht einen Blick in seinen Korb werfen kann, um zu sehen, ob er leer ist? Das bestreite ich. Aufteilen kann man auch, ohne sich selbst einen Anteil zuzuschanzen. Verteilen vs. Austeilen: Man kann ein Erbe schon ver- oder aufteilen, während man noch lebt, aber erst nach dem Tod wird es ausgeteilt. Das mit dem Stromverteiler stimmt m.E. nicht. Auch die umgefallene Obstkiste muss nicht vollständig leer werden - dennoch verteilen sich die Äpfel über die Straße.

Comment: Abschnitt Aufteilen, Satz 2 bitte noch mal Korrekturlesen. Ist "Anspruchshaltung" gemeint?

Comment: Eine Politesse, die Strafzettel verteilt, wird das allen bösen Gerüchten zum Trotz hoffentlich nicht mit der Zielsetzung tun, jeden einzelnen Zettel ihres Knöllchen-Blocks loszuwerden.